# ATX hard disk activity led wiring

Tags: atx

How is the hdd activity led wired according to the ATX specification? Is it like this?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpUOP1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If so, what is the 5V voltage relative to? PSU 5V and PSU 5V ground? It appears that I always get 5 V regardless of activity, when measuring between hdd+ and PSU 5V ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most often the LED positive side is not switched, it comes always from power supply and negative rail is driven low to turn on the LED. Your measurements verify that this is the case. If you need to see this then put multimeter lead to LED negative side.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more or possibly add a schematic (or alter the OP's original schematic)?  I'm a newbie and very curious about how this works. I think you are saying there is always 5V across the LED but then only when the LED is driven low does it actually turn on but I'm not sure how that works.  I appreciate any additional details you can offer. Thx - Also if you can create a 5V circuit I could build with an LED that works that way I would very much appreciate it. I'd love to build that circuit and see the LED light up only when it gets taken low as an experiment.

Comment: No there is not 5V always across the LED, otherwise it would blow up. Just imagine there is a pushbutton between battery negative and LED negative terminals. Pushing it will complete the circuit, current flows and LED is turned on. If not pushed, there is no current flowing so there is 5V across the switch. In reality that would be a transistor on motherboard.